# I am trying to get data using requests. The data which I am supposed to get is in json format. How doI print it?

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests

This is my code.I am trying to get the values(they are in json format refer to the link below) but I do not know how.
I have tried running the code below

python code :

```
abc = c.get('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/')
        #aaa = json.loads(abc)
        print abc
```

this [link](http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html) will provide more info about json and website

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
print dict(abc)
```

requests response has a method called json(). But it only works if there is any json data. So if your request is returning any data then use as follows.

```
print abc.json()
```

I went through the link you have mentioned above, and there is no GET request mentioned there. Hence it is returning nothing. So the

```
print dict(abc)
```

will print an empty dictionary. But you can always check with the attributes provided with the response object. You can refer to [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) for further study.

Answer (score 0):

REST API you mentioned is POST call where you have to post text for analysis. Please refer to following python code.

import requests

```
abc = requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', data={"text":"great"})
print abc
```

If you want to know content of the response:

```
print abc.text
```

The response I got:

```
{"probability": {"neg": 0.30135019761690551, "neutral": 0.27119050546800266, "pos": 0.69864980238309449}, "label": "pos"}
```

Comment: how do i  print only the label?